# Best way to save object's data in php?

Tags: php, session, authentication, logging

I am trying to create a log in system in php. I have 3 files. index.php, login.class.php (defines Login class), securePage.php.

Login class has different functions such as getUserName(), addUser(), etc.

index.php creates a new $login object, has a log in form and create a new account form.

When you create an account on the index.php page, 
$login->addUser($username, $password, $first_name, $last_name, $email); function executes which creates a new account.

After you log in and hit submit, the script checks your username/password/etc and redirects you to securePage.php.

After I redirect to securePage.php from the login.class.php, I am not sure what's the best way to check if the user has logged in correctly and have all the user's information handy.

Right now my securePage.php creates a new login object
$login = new Login; and checks if the user has access to the page by calling checkAccess within the Login class.

// Check if the user has access to this page, otherwise redirect to login page

```
if($login->checkAccess()) {
   //blah blah blah
}
```

This is how checkAccess function looks inside Login Class

```
public function checkAccess() {

    // check the session access
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) ) {
        //
        return true;
    }

}
```

I feel this is bad implementation because 
a) I create a brand new login object and lose my data 
b) I only check if the session is secure by checking if session's username is set which can be probably faked.

What's the best way to implement securePage.php in terms of still having all the user data and checking if the user is logged in?

Comment: session cookie at server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session data is server side data -- it can only be faked through manually guessing PHPSESSIONID (You can read up on that [here](http://segfaultlabs.com/files/pdf/php-session-security.pdf)).

The way that this is normally handled is one of two ways. If HTTP Authentication is being used (which has some major benefits, BTW), then basically every time a secure transaction needs to occur, the UN/PW have to be tested. On the other hand, if the server is storing the value (say in `$_SESSION` or some other framework equivalent), then the server already has the data and there is no point in re-querying.

If you have implemented the methods [`__sleep` and `__wakeup`](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.magic-functions.php) properly, you can simply store the entire login object in `$_SESSION`, which would generally be my preference.

Comment: Exactly. You can add more checks and restrictions, obviously at the risk of inconveniencing legitimate users. I'd argue that unless it's really mission critical, sessions are more than enough.

Comment: I do not have __sleep and __wakeup implemented. Is there another way to pass that information besides putting the entire login object in SESSION

Comment: If it is a simple object, then storing the entire thing in SESSION is really your best option. If it isn't simple, then you could probably decouple some of that logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your session is stored server side, and thus is a good way to check for a login status. There are some issues like f.e. account sharing but they shouldn't be a problem for the application you are developing.

I wouldn't be checking on the username though, I'd add a key called 'authorised' or something. also I'd call the function isAuthorised instead of checkAccess, as checkAccess would indicate using user roles/rights to me.

Comment: Is there a way I can pass an object to my securePage.php instead of creating a new one without serialization (I will probably implement that but I am wondering if there is another way)

Comment: Without serialisation in the session/memcached/database or an other storage? No.